# How to add a flexible space or Toolbar action icon obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, toolbar

How can i add action listener in flexible space or Toolbar. I create 
- (IBAction)TouchOnFixedButton:(id)sender; for flexible space. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a gesture recognizer to your toolbar, then check tap location.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:)))
navigationController?.toolbar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gesture.locationInView(navigationController!.toolbar)
    print(location.x)
}
```

Comment: Thank You ...I will test it ...If u can add in obj-c too it will  better for me ...

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this,

```
  UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                               target:self action:@selector(done:)];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];

// Flexible space as below


UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                      CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                 myPicker.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          cancelButton,flexibleSpace,doneButton,nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
myTextfield.inputView = myPicker;
myTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

This is simple example. you can manage according to your need.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

As per apple doc when you add flexible space:

> Blank space to add between other items. The space is distributed
>   equally between the other items. Other item properties are ignored
>   when this value is set.

So, other values are ignored. Thats why your method is not called. You can derive a custom ToolBar and can override touchEvent to capture them.